# How do I update other Microsoft libraries after updating to .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a web app solution that is quite old where the main project is Asp.Net 4.6 and a small companion project is .Net Core 2.

I want to first upgrade them both to .Net Core 3.1, and then upgrade to .Net 7 later this year.

According to the Microsoft documentation I have to update the target framework and associated libraries.

So I updated this part in my project file:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

However, the other referenced libraries don't seem to have 3.1 updates.  How would I upgrade these?

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="2.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.3.0" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Microsoft introduced .NET Core 3.0, they stopped producing a large number of NuGet packages (If you're interested, you can see the list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references)).

Microsoft made them part of the shared framework `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` that is implicitly referenced if your `.csproj` targets `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK. You can check this in your `.csproj` project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  ...
</Project>
```

If your project targets `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`, then you might have to add a `FrameworkReference`, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference).

Assuming the latter is not your case, removing the references to those NuGet packages should be fine.

Comment: So I can just delete all the old package references that are no longer supported out of my project file?  Then add in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`?  Thanks!

Comment: So I checked and the first line says `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` So does that mean I can just delete them all?  Thanks!

Comment: The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` ones can be deleted, as they're referenced in the list I mentioned. The `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.*` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.*` ones have versions that target .NET Core 3.1. The `System.*` you should be able to also upgrade them all, as they should be compatible.

Comment: The `System.*` ones are for old ASP.NET Framework.  I want to upgrade to .Net Core 3.1, do I still need them? I checked and there are no upgrades available for .Net Core...just the ASP.NET Framework.  Thanks!

Comment: `System.*` ones have versions available that target .NET Standard 1.1 or higher, which makes them compatible with .NET Core 3.1. Answering the question, I believe you don't need `System.Net.Http`, as it's included in the framework.

The other two packages are not, and I know they are used when you consume a WCF Web Service for instance. Therefore, I would remove and see if the project compiles - as it could happen that they aren't being used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For microsoft .net core  packages,I think you could search in the document and found the correspond  packages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-2.2

example1:

[image]

[image]

example2:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you find the page that shoes you the `Package` name and version?  when I go there, I do see a section called `Definition`.  Thanks!